# How to create an outlook message from an event using graph api?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

You can create reply/replyAll/forward from an outlook message, but how to create from an event? Is there an API or you have to structure the new email yourself using the data returned by the event?

Comment: You can try using the [eventMessage Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/eventmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I don't have eventMessage in the context. What I'm trying to do is open an event from Calendar and create a reply from it as you can do from Outlook.

Comment: @H Z, Got it. That feature is not present yet in MS Graph. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)